# MongoDB Double Keys

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

This document is in my db (copied from mongo cl client):

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52d14a3c10df410253000000"),
  "content" : "U2FsdGVkX1/rU5DJTu/VYGCGxV1lHhhs1l2b3LZJXBQ=\n",
  "content" : "U2FsdGVkX1/rU5DJTu/VYGCGxV1lHhhs1l2b3LZJXBQ=\n",
  "created_at" : ISODate("2014-01-11T14:19:09.840Z"),
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-23T16:38:48.283Z"),
  "user_id" : ObjectId("51cd7edb25bbe84f67000001")
}
```

"content" field is saved twice somehow. How can this happen and how can I prevent it in the future?

I am using Mongoid 4.0.0.beta1 with MongoDB 2.4.9.

Comment: I would have said it's not possible, but here it is.  How did you add this doc to the collection?

Comment: I am not sure as of yet but will try to consistently reproduce and post a recipe as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The issue must be on your client side. Natively mongo supports fields with the same name in one document but according to the documentation it will never add a duplicate field to an existing document.

> BSON documents may have more than one field with the same name. Most
>   MongoDB interfaces, however, represent MongoDB with a structure (e.g.
>   a hash table) that does not support duplicate field names. If you need
>   to manipulate documents that have more than one field with the same
>   name, see the driver documentation for your driver.
>
> Some documents created by internal MongoDB processes may have
>   duplicate fields, but no MongoDB process will ever add duplicate
>   fields to an existing user document.

Hope it helps!